Asset library not showing since upgrade to 4.1 but only in one job
I have an archvis project I have been working on and save new versions as I work along. I upgraded to 4.1 and this one job, that I have done a lot of work on, will not show any assets in the asset library except those I just added since upgrading. Now, the odd thing is, it is only that job. i can start new jobs, pull up old jobs and all my assets are visible in the library, it is just that one job. I have tried clearing the file paths in preferences and reloading but that doesn't help, it still will not see assets but all the other jobs, and new jobs will. I have tried "save as" with this job but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to repair the links inside that job? I have tried "refresh library" but that does nothing. It won't even show the Hair essentials that come in the basic Blender install.

Never could find a way to clean up the library so I opened a new job in a new window, went back to the original and copied the main collection, which held everything in the job, and pasted it the new job and everything was there plus the library worked. Must have been something corrupted in that job.
